# stream m3u8 stopped before start

Tags: ffmpeg

I have m3u8 link and RTMP server. I wanna stream from m3u8 linkt to RTMP server but when i call command

ffmpeg   -re -stream_loop -1 -i   xxx.m3u8 -c:v copy -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ab 128k -ac 2 -strict -2 -flags +global_header -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -bufsize 2000k -f flv rtmp://xxx

then ffmpeg show "DONE" but not stream.

> [7] 21629
>   ffmpeg version N-97584-gf821ae8 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
>     built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 20160609
>     configuration: --enable-openssl --disable-x86asm
>     libavutil      56. 43.100 / 56. 43.100
>     libavcodec     58. 82.100 / 58. 82.100
>     libavformat    58. 42.102 / 58. 42.102
>     libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
>     libavfilter     7. 80.100 /  7. 80.100
>     libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
>     libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
>   -c:v: command not found
>
> [7]+  **Stopped**                 ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i https://

Answer (score 1):

the URL you are using has a characters such as `&` or `;` that are being interpreted by the shell. Place the url in quotes.

e.g. `ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i "xxx.m3u8" -c:v copy -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ab 128k -ac 2 -strict -2 -flags +global_header -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -bufsize 2000k -f flv rtmp://xxx`